# Protractor Test is extremely slow and often times out

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, protractor

I've been battling this test most of the afternoon, I've commented out what I tried to do but it wouldn't work. I have the ability the search for users within the company, a table is then generated and I want to select the one that matches the name of the user. Currently I just use td.text-center as it is the only td in the table, but this seems really poor and prone to breaking if other users with the same name are in the system.

Attempt 2 seems like it would be the best solution but it always gives the element not found error. Has anyone found a reliable way of locating TD within a table? The method below works in other tables, just not this one....

```
  this.editUser = function(name) {

        // Original Code Block
        //browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.css('td.text-center'))).perform();
        //var editUserBtn = element(by.css('.user-action-open'));
        //editUserBtn.click().then(function() {
        //    var editDetails = element(by.cssContainingText('li > a', 'Edit Details'));
        //    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(editDetails), 3000);
        //    editDetails.click();
        //});


        // Attempt 2

        // browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.css('td.text-center'))).perform();
        //browser.sleep(3000);
        //var edit = element.all(by.repeater('user in users')).filter(function(rowElement){
        //    return rowElement.element.all(by.css('td[ng-bind="user.Firstname"]')).getText().then(function(text){
        //        return text.trim() == name;
        //    });
        //}).first();
        //browser.actions().mouseMove(edit).perform();


        // Currently just times out and doesn't find the element.

        var editUserButton = $('.user-action-open');
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(editUserButton), 20000).then(function() {
            editUserButton.click().then(function() {
                var editDetails = element(by.cssContainingText('li > a', 'Edit Details'));
                browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(editDetails), 3000);
                editDetails.click();
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ExpectedConditions` to do some waiting instead of arbitrarily sleeping for 3 seconds. You could instead do a browser wait. This will wait up to the timeout if the object is in a desired state.

```
    let users = element.all(by.repeater('user in users');

    // the original post shows that this is an element.all
    // this would only be true if the user can have multiple first names
    let firstName = element(by.css('td[ng-bind="user.Firstname"]'));

    browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.css('td.text-center'))).perform();

    // wait to see if the repeater is present or timeout in 3 seconds
    browser.wait(users).isPresent(), 3000);

    let edit = element.all(users).filter((rowElement) => {
      // wait for first name, get the first name of the row's element
      // if the text matches the name, resolve the promise true.
      return browser.wait(rowElement.firstName, 3000).then(() => {
        return rowElement.firstName.getText().then((text) => {
          return text.trim() == name;
        });
      });
    }).first();

    browser.actions().mouseMove(edit).perform();
```

The `rowElement.firstName` might not be the correct syntax.

---

Chaining the promises

```
  // wait to see if the repeater is present or timeout in 3 seconds
  browser.wait(users).isPresent(), 3000).then(() => {
    let edit = element.all(users).filter((rowElement) => {
      // wait for first name, get the first name of the row's element
      // if the text matches the name, resolve the promise true.
      return browser.wait(rowElement.firstName, 3000).then(() => {
        return rowElement.firstName.getText().then((text) => {
          return text.trim() == name;
        });
      });
    }).first();

    browser.actions().mouseMove(edit).perform();
  }).catch(err => {
    // we could also have asserted the length was at least 1
    // maybe we want to catch on something else? maybe this isn't a
    // fail case so maybe do not use `fail(`
    fail("did not find users"); 
  });
```

Comment: that looks good, I guess the main thing I was trying to do was remove the browser.actions.mouseMove to hover the row, and replace it with a loop filter to just find the row and click it instead, for whatever reason I can't seem to do it so will try this method

Comment: If you are trying to just click on an object, just make sure that it is available to click on. The arbitrary timeout is not ideal. Also, I was not sure why there was a mouse move. I decided that it had something to do with a menu that appeared after hovering over `'td.text-center'`. Another thing that is missing is the click action if you are planning to click on it.

Comment: Yeah its not an ideal design, but has to be worked with. Basically It generates a table, when the td is hovered a button to edit that particular row appears, hence the hacky code to get the row to show, but I feel this setup is prone to breaking due to the fact it relies on the search returning a single td row.

Comment: updated answer above. we could also wrap it in a then / catch statement. if it is not there, then in our catch we can handle that error. possibly it isn't an error and we should do something else. anyway, i hope that helps.